# How to delete files in the app's sandbox?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a `UITableView` set up and its data source is the app's sandbox, so all the rows are filled with the files that were imported using `UIDocumentPicker`, but I also need to be able to delete those files.

The delete function works, I am able to slide and delete a row and everything, but the file stays in the app's sandbox, so every time I import a new file, the rows are refilled (the *TableView* reloads every time something is imported) with the previously "deleted" stuff.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            self.deleteFile()
            importedfiles.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }

 }
```

Plus everything that is in the code already, I need the function to delete the file from the app's sandbox (importedfiles).

Here's what I've got so far, I am able to delete files, but only the entire directory, which is not what I want. Code:

```
   func deleteFile() {
        let dirPaths = FM.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0].path

        if FM.fileExists(atPath: docsDir) {
            do {
                try FM.removeItem(atPath: docsDir)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: "importedfiles" are files that were imported in the app's directory (documents) using UIDocumentPickerViewController. And the TableView uses this data to create cells.

Comment: That code attempts to remove the entire Documents folder. Don't do that. You need the path to just the one file you wish to delete.

Comment: You don't have a parameter in your deleteFile func, I assume you want to send the row from `importedfiles` that you deleted (so you need to call deleteFile before you remove it from the array). What is the type if the array, is it `[URL]`?

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for that! And yes, it is an URL.

Comment: @rmaddy, Yeah... I just can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: You have not provided any details about your files in your question. Please update your question and show relevant information about the files you wish to delete. Does your data model have at least the filename? Where are the files stored (such as maybe the Documents folder)? Show details about what `importedfiles` is.

Comment: @rmaddy, it should be enough (see edit), let me know if you need to know more!

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete method to

```
func deleteFile(_ url: URL) {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fm.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and call it

```
if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
    self.deleteFile(importedfiles[indexPath.row])
    importedfiles.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
}
```

This should work but there is no error handling and if you want that you can define your method to return `Result`

```
func deleteFile(_ url: URL) -> Result<Void,Error> {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fm.removeItem(at: url)
        return .success(())
    } catch {
        return .failure(error)
    }
}
```

and handle the result in a `switch`

```
let result = deleteFile(importedfiles[indexPath.row])
switch result {
case .success:
    //Maybe update array and table view here
case .failure(let error):
     //dislplay error?
}
```